# Map array of values to a new array with a specific range

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I have an array of values like this:

```
var values = [3452,1234,200,783,77]
```

What I need to do is to map these values to a new array where the values should fall in a range between 10 and 90.

```
var new_values = [12,48,67,78,90]
```

Is there a way to achieve this in native JS?

Kind of stuck :(
Thanks

Comment: What is the calculation you're using to determine 12 from 3452 and so on?

Comment: Or do you mean *filter*?

Comment: Do you want to filter the first array ? If so, look at the filter method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Please show some reasonable input and your expected output *from that input*.

Comment: @T.J.: it was just an example to me, only to say the initial values should be "translated" into  other values, on the basis of the range provided. not really tried anything particular, cause I don't know if it's possible (did not find anything similar yet)

Answer (score 3):

If you really mean *map* (exchange one value for another), that's `Array#map`:

```
var new_array = array.map(function(value) {
    return /*...calculation on value...*/;
});
```

It will call your callback with each value from the array and build a new array from the values it returns. *(Apologies, I couldn't figure out how 3452 becomes 12 and 1234 becomes 48, etc.)*

For instance, this doubles:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var new_array = array.map(function(value) {
  return value * 2;
});
console.log(new_array);
```

If you mean *filter* (only keep values in range), it's `Array#filter`:

```
var new_array = array.filter(function(value) {
    return value >= 10 && value <= 90;
});
```

It will call your callback with each value from the array and build a new array out of only the values you return a truthy value for. I've interpreted "between 10 and 90" as being inclusive of 10 and 90.

Example:

```js
var array = [3452,1234,200,783,77];
var new_array = array.filter(function(value) {
    return value >= 10 && value <= 90;
});
console.log(new_array);
```

---

In ES2015 (aka "ES6") and above, those can be more concise:

```
let new_array = array.map(value => /*...calculation on value...*/);
```

or

```
let new_array = array.filter(value => value >= 10 && value <= 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clamp:

`var new_values = [3452,1234,200,783,77].map(n => Math.Min(10, Math.max(n, 90)));`

To filter:

`var new_values = [3452,1234,200,783,77].filter(n => 10 < n && n < 90));`